# How do I install AMD drivers?

Tags: release-hera, graphic-drivers, drivers, amd

I installed a fresh copy of elementary os 5.1.2 Hera and my gpu fan is cranked up to about 50% all the time it sounds like. I have a feeling it has to do with it missing a driver. So how can I install a driver for an HD 7570 graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

The eOS distribution already has the Open Source AMD drivers included in the MESA and the Linux Kernel. If you wish, you can download and install the FULL AMD Drivers ([follow this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux))